# How to assign requests from each user always to a same instance in an instance group?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, parallel-processing, gunicorn, autoscaling

I have a deep learning web application deployed in GCE. I created a template to build a VM instance group. Then added loading balancing to it.

I plan that when each user accesses the URL, the requests from the same user will always be assigned to a VM instance. I use `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app -t 600` as part of the startup script. (I also tried with workers, gevent. But requests from different users can be handled in the same instance, as a result of which, the results were affected by each other. So I want requests from different users to be handled in different instances.)

To do so, I tried different CPU utilization for autoscaling. It can autoscale with new instances. But from the results, sometimes the requests are still handled in the same instance.

I also tried Kurbenetes, app engine, and cloud run. Mistakes are similar. I feel I am working in the wrong direction.

Thanks in advance.

---UPDATE---

As mentioned by @John Hanley, assigning requests from a user always to the same instance is not the targeted feature of these products. If you are looking for the answer to this question, you may try the Cloud Tasks + App Engine.

Actually, I want requests from different users to be handled in different instances so that the back-end deep learning algorithm's results cannot affect each other.

So, instead of spinning up an instance, another way to solve this is to store necessary data from each user in a common database with a unique session ID.
A simple demo can be found in https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/getting-started/session-handling-with-firestore

Hope this can be helpful for anyone struggling with similar problems.

Comment: You are trying to use Google load balancing and autoscaling as a "job" management feature. That is not a supported objective for those features. Instead, rethink your design in that each request is a "job" and then spin up an instance or service to handle that job. There are services such as Cloud Tasks that can help you, but you will need to implement this yourself. Depending on your software, Cloud Run can handle one request per service instance.

Comment: @JohnHanley, Thanks for your reply. I tired Cloud Run with max request for each instance to 1. The results were still mixed with each other as they were in  GCE. I think it is because the requests from the same user are not necessarily handled in a same instance. So, the backend deep learning model in one instance may process requests from other users. I am looking at Cloud Tasks now, hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment section by @John Hanley, the best approach would be to use App Engine + Cloud Tasks, I suggest you to check the next [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/develop-your-cloud-tasks-pipeline-locally-with-ngrok-5bee3693600f), although it uses ngrok instead of unicorn the idea of the of the workflow should be similar for what you want to achieve.